# Convention for running rails seeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 7
```

Per the tutorial I am following, to run specific seed files, I am supposed to create the following folder structure:

```
 /db/seeds
```

And in that folder, I place my seed file:

```
/db/seeds/authors.seeds.rb
```

In /db/seeds/authors.seeds.rb, I have:

```
authors = [
    {"first" => "John", "last" => "Doe"},
    {"first" => "Jane", "last" => "Doe"}
]
authors.each do |a|
  Author.create!(a)
end
```

When I try to run it as:

```
rails db:seeds:authors --trace
```

I get the following error:

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:seeds:authors' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
.../rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:59:in `[]'
.../rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:159:in `invoke_task'
.../rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
.../rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
.../rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
.../rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
.../rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
.../railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
.../rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
.../railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block in perform'
.../rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
.../railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
.../railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:51:in `invoke'
.../railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
.../bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
.../bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I checked and the table is there.

## Edit:

When I put copy the contents of /db/seeds/authors.seeds.rb to /db/seeds.rb and then run:

```
rake db:seed
```

It executes properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to run `rake db:seed` only in your terminal, remove the *authors* keyword

Comment: That will end up running the db/seeds.rb file or will run all the seeds. I only want to run a single seeds file